# Difference problem in finding word count in PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, regex, replace, preg-replace

There are 2 codes, PHP and JS. The work of the codes is exactly the same.

The duty of the codes is to count words. However, there is 1 difference between PHP and JS results.

The reason for this difference is due to the "line". How can I solve this problem.

I want both codes to give the same values.

### PHP CODE:

**PHP Result:** 19

```
<?php

    function character_count($str){
        $str = preg_replace("/<\/?[a-z][^>]*>/i", "", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/&nbsp;+/", " ", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\n+/", "", $str);
        $str = mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8');
        return $str;
    }
    
    $string = '<p>Hello World</p>
<p>Welcome</p>';
    
    echo character_count($string);
```

PHP CODE TEST: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64dac96d1406e2e7352858f8563f82378929eeb3

---

### JS CODE:

**JS Result:** 18

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1></h1>

<script>
    function character_count(str){
        return str ? str.replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*>/gi, "").replace(/&nbsp;+/g, " ").replace(/\n+/, "").length : 0;
    }
    
    var string = '<p>Hello World</p>\n' +
        '<p>Welcome</p>';
    
    $("h1").text(character_count(string));    
</script>
```

Comment: the string is not same, in `php` you have a space between two `<p>` in `js` no.

Comment: You mean the difference is because the php counts new lines too? If yes then change the `replace(/\n+/, "")` in the js function to the `replace(/\n+/, " ")`. Then the problem will be solved

Comment: i think yes, if you try to delete that space the count is same.

Comment: the new line is counted too

Comment: @Ashkan The problem was resolved when I made the change you specified. I'm doing a few tries. Thanks

Comment: @Ashkan ```.replace(/\n+/, " ")```   
    The problem is solved again when I delete it from the JS section. Will there be a different problem later ? What is the meaning of this ?

Comment: As @SimoneRossaini said, the string in php code is different from the string in js. 
Use this `$str = preg_replace("/\r\n+/", "", $str);` instead of `$str = preg_replace("/\r\n+/", "", $str);` in php function and use the previous `replace(/\n+/, "")` for js function. then the results would be same: 18

Comment: @Ashkan after this change, the results change a lot.

Comment: Line breaks in PHP are matched with `\R`, so use `preg_replace("/\R+/", "", $str);`. In JS, to match any line break chars you need `/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g`

Comment: `function character_count($str){
        $str = preg_replace("/<\/?[a-z][^>]*>/i", "", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/&nbsp;+/", " ", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\R+/", "", $str);
        $str = mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8');
        return $str;
    }`

Comment: `function _character_count(str){
            return str ? str.replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*>/gi, "").replace(/&nbsp;+/g, " ").replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g, "").length : 0;
        }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew These last changes I made are working properly. Thank you.